# "another subsequent"?

Tags: grammar

Can I use **another subsequent** to mean "subsequent of subsequent", like below?

*Send 1, 2, and 3 in order: Enter 1 in the first email, enter 2 in a subsequent email, and enter 3 in **another subsequent** email.*

Comment: It simply means another email that is subsequent.  Subsequent to what is unclear.

Comment: @HotLicks, Well... then how can I express something subsequent to a previously mentioned subsequent thing? How about "a next subsequent email"?